# Executing stored procedure returns syntax error but running query works

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns a syntax error when executed. However running the query on SQL Server Management studio works.

The syntax error is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 96
>   Incorrect syntax near 'se'.

The full stored procedure is here:
https://pastebin.com/nnQ65KPM

I have narrowed the problem to the last CTE. When this block is removed the stored procedure executes fine. All CTEs used in `WellTestDetails_CTE` work fine as well.

```
WellTestDetails_CTE (testmonth, well, result) as
(
    select 
        b.month as testmonth, a.well, a.result 
    from 
        (select 
             well, result, result_no
         from 
             (select * from WellTest1 
              union 
              select * from WellTest2) a 
         join     
             [Digital_Ecosystem_DEV].[dbo].[OrgAssigments] b on a.SUBFACILITY = b.SubFacility 
         where  
             b.team = ''X'') x 
    join 
        WellTestGrouped_CTE y on x.result_no = y.result_no       
)
select * 
from WellTestDetails
```

Comment: The previous statement needs to be terminated by a semi-colon when defining a CTE, for some reason. In a stand-alone query there is no previous statement. Try `;WellTestDetails_CTE ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `@SQL` variable in `DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)` is too small for all the dynamic SQL, try `DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine now after changing @sql size :)

Comment: Glad i could help :)